# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 8, got 1)

Tags: python

Is there something wrong with my split function?

```py
import sys
import os
import re

filename= "data.txt"
mydata= []
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    print(f)
    for i in f:
            line = 0
            line += 1

record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value = i.split('|')

            line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = True)    

            if field_type == 'N':
                if character_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or numeric_value == ' ':
                            line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = False)        
            elif field_type == 'C':
                    if numeric_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or character_value == ' ':
                            line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = False)        

            elif field_type == 'D':
                    if numeric_value != ' ' or character_value != ' ' or date_value == ' ':
                            line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = False)
def makeLineToPrint(ok):
    if ok:
        line_to_print = "{}{} OK--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)
    else:
         line_to_print = "{}{} NO--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, size, record_number, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)
    return line_to_print

print(line_to_print)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your for loop within the `with open()` indentation like so:

```
with open(filename,"r") as f:
    for i in f:
       do_stuff()
```

I've fixed the indentation errors and moved the function definition right after imports.

```
import sys
import os
import re

def makeLineToPrint(ok):
    if ok:
        line_to_print = "{}{} OK--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)
    else:
        line_to_print = "{}{} NO--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, size, record_number, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)
    return line_to_print

filename= "data.txt"
mydata= []
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    print(next(f))
    line = 0
    for i in f:
        line += 1

        record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value = i.split('|')

        line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = True)    

        if field_type == 'N':
            if character_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or numeric_value == ' ':
                        line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = False)        
        elif field_type == 'C':
                if numeric_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or character_value == ' ':
                        line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = False)        

        elif field_type == 'D':
                if numeric_value != ' ' or character_value != ' ' or date_value == ' ':
                        line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = False)
        print(line_to_print)
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. do i need to move my makelinetoprint function then?

Comment: yes, function definitions should come right after imports.

Comment: update your question with the new code and the error you are seeing. i also suggest adding  `print(f)` right after your `with open() as f:` statement to validate you are opening the file successfully.

Comment: Hi, do you know what this means? "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 8, got 1)"

Comment: the line you are trying to i.split("|") doesn't have any "|". I assume the first line of data.txt is a header? if so you can add a check in your for loop `if line== 0:` `line+=1` `continue` or the way you solved it before `next(f)`

Comment: first line is: 12|15|joe|2|N|15| | |